# Fix indentation of LaTeX code without wrapping lines

Tags: latex, indentation, auctex

If I select everything in LaTeX-mode (AUCTeX) and auto-fill the region, the indentation of all lines is corrected. This is the part I like.

However, it also breaks all long lines (which I think is the actual purpose of that function). But I don't like hard line wrapping.

Is there a way I can fix the indentation of an entire file without the lines being wrapped in the actual text? Wrapping them in the displayed text is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to indent a region, you should call an [indenting function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html#Indentation), not a filling function that, as you guessed, [is meant to break lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Filling.html#Filling).

For example, you can use <kbd>C-M-\</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `indent-region` <kbd>RET</kbd>) to indent the active region.